# Using jQuery validation plugin with a form written in struts

Tags: javascript, jsp, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, struts

I want to implement the jQuery validation plugin for use in a web application written in java and struts. I just want to use it to validate form inputs to see if they conform to certain rules before it's submitted to a database. The project I'm trying to implement this in was written by someone else, I don't have access to them, and I can't rewrite it.

Here is one of the form inputs that I want to validate:

```
<html:text property="groomFirstName" maxlength="30" tabindex="1" styleId="groomFirstName"  size="15" onchange="properCase(this.id); needToConfirm=true;"   />
```

I've written some custom methods for the plugin. I have tested them on a simple HTML form, but I don't how to make them work with the struts code like the line of code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that Struts is used to generate the form is irrelevant. JavaScript executes in the browser, and HTML is HTML.

The line of code above is not HTML. It's a Struts JSP tag that is evaluated at server-side and generates HTML code that is sent to the browser. jQuery only cares about the HTML. And the above code will generate the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="groomFirstName" maxlength="30" tabindex="1" 
       id="groomFirstName" size="15" 
       onchange="properCase(this.id); needToConfirm=true;" />
```