# Using Struts html tag, render attribute not present in TLD

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-validate, struts, struts-1

I'm trying to validate Struts 1.3 - made forms with [jQuery Validator](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin. Even though Struts 1.x has reached it's end-of-life, I'm not allowed to switch to another MVC framework.

jQuery validator uses attributes on `<input>` tag to determine which validation rules to apply. For example:

```
<input type="text" minlenght="30" required />
```

will check if the textbox was filled in and it's contents length is at least of 30.

I'm trying to achieve the same with `<html:text>`, which is supposed to render as an `<input type="text">` element. But `minlength` and `required` are not defined in struts-html.tld as attributes, causing the JSP compiler to throw the following (translated from Spanish) exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/path-to-my-jsp Attribute xxx invalid for tag xxx according to TLD
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758729/using-jquery-validation-plugin-with-a-form-written-in-struts) it is possible, despite the fact that Struts is used to generate the form. But I couldn't make it work.

Is there any way to force the JSP compiler to ignore those undefined attributes and make Struts render them "as-is"?

Note: I've chosen jQuery Validator due to it's ease of use, but I'm open to suggestions on other methods to perform the same task. However, I still want to know if it's possible to make the JSP compiler to ignore an invalid / undefined attribute.

P.S. Please excuse my english. I've tried my best.

Comment: I don't think their is way to force the JSP compiler to ignore those undefined attributes.

Comment: you can edit tld and related file to add attribute to it

Comment: You've misspelled `minlength` as `minlenght`.  Perhaps this is your compilation error?

Comment: @rajeshkakawat not a bad idea, but having too many rules, plus the possibility to add custom ones, multiplied by the different input types, makes it hard to maintain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"jQuery validator uses attributes on  tag to determine which
>   validation rules to apply."*

```
<input type="text" minlenght="30" required />
```

---

You *do not have to* declare rules using HTML5 attributes.

You could instead declare your rules from within the `.validate()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            fieldname: {  // <- field name attribute
                required: true,
                minlength: 30
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Corresponding HTML**:

```
<input type="text" name="fieldname" />
```

**NOTE**: the jQuery Validate plugin **mandates** that the `input` field contains a unique `name` attribute ***no matter how** the rules are applied*.  The `name` attribute is how the plugin keeps track of the inputs.  If you fail to assign a unique `name` attribute, the plugin will behave unpredictably or not at all.

---

**I just noticed that you've misspelled the `minlength` rule as `minlenght`.  Perhaps this is the root cause of your compilation error?**

Comment: Your tip was very helpful. Actually I didn't copy/paste the real code (my fault). I just tried to write an understandable example. The above java exception is thrown with any attribute not declared in TLD, misspelled or not.